# How to reduce left margin of div if contained element's size is too large?

Tags: html, css

I have text with equations that I want to format for the web. The equations are in the form of embedded SVG. In the example below I replaced them with a fixed-sized `div`. This SVG element is inside a `div` explicitly meant to contain the SVG.

The equations have a small (in the example, 3em) margin on the left. This is accomplished by setting the margin of the containing `div`

Large equations (too wide to fit the page) need to be scaled down. I accomplish this by setting the `svg` `max-width` property to 100%. However, it looks a little funny scaling down the equation but leaving the relatively large left margin intact. So I'm looking to also reduce the size of this margin if the SVG's size is larger than the 100% width allocated to it.

I'm sure there's a straight-forward way to accomplish this, but I can't seem to find any solutions.

In the example below, `#equation2` is too wide, and being scaled down. How can I reduce the margin of the containing div as well? (If I need to rethink the HTML structure, this is fine too.)

```css
html {
  background-color: red;
}
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 20em;
}
div.math {
  margin-left: 3em;
}
div.math div {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#equation1 {
  height: 1em;
  width: 8em;
  background-color: gray;
}
#equation2 {
  height: 1em;
  width: 30em;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<html><body>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
<div class='math'>
  <div id='equation1'></div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
<div class='math'>
  <div id='equation2'></div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: what i understand that you need the svg to be inline with the text.. so why not using grid or flexbox ?

Comment: @Burham: The HTML is generated by Markdown. I can change the elements surrounding the SVG (it's a Markdown plugin I made myself). And I can change the HTML outside the main text (it's a template). Would that be sufficient to implement what you're thinking? What would that look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flexbox and simulate the margin with a pseudo element then you can rely on the shrink effect:

```css
html {
  background-color: red;
}
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 20em;
}
div.math {
  display:flex;
}
div.math::before {
  content:"";
  flex-basis:3em;
  flex-shrink:3; /* control the shrink factor*/
  min-width:5px; /* define a min value*/
}

div.math > div {
  height: 1em;
  width: 8em;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
<div class='math'>
  <div id='equation1'></div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
<div class='math'>
  <div id='equation2' style="width:20em"></div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
<div class='math'>
  <div id='equation2' style="width:23em"></div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
<div class='math'>
  <div id='equation2' style="width:25em"></div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
<div class='math'>
  <div id='equation2' style="width:30em"></div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Many thanks. These flex boxes really make a lot of things simpler. I'm surprised this requires so little CSS.